# SCons cannot find 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp'

Tags: c++, boost, scons

I am trying to use the open-source code [ciGen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cigen/) for my FE analysis, but it needs to be compiled first. The author of this code says that I have to use SCons and have the Boost libraries. I have installed both of them and added them to the path. However, when I type "scons" in cmd to compile the files, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(341): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\empadaten\abaqus\igen\interface-generator\src\typedefs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory
scons: *** [AbaqusMeshWriter.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The warning is maybe not so important (I don't know, I kept it here just in case). I have checked a lot of forums, user manuals etc. but I am anything but familiar with any programming language. If anyone can guide me through this in any way possible, I would be more than glad.

Comment: you can take a look at Makefile inside the src folder. INCLUDEDIRS entry should refer to the root folder of boost library.

Comment: @yildirim thank you for the suggestion. I copied the boost folder directory to Makefile, yet I still get the identical error.

Comment: If you modify the Makefile, then you should use make to build it.  Otherwise you'll need to modify the SConstruct (which is currently very minimal).